# How to change the font color of Syncfusion Autocomplete ( On Selected row )

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, syncfusion

I have a autocomplete from Syncfusion. (In winforms App)
look at the following screenshot
[image]

When user type a text on the box autocomplete appears. I need to change the fore color of the selection.

```
public Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Tools.AutoComplete autoComplete;
```

I tried to set the color like this. But seems its not working
Cant see any property to to do this.
Plz help

```
  autoComplete.SetAutoComplete(txtSymbol, AutoCompleteModes.MultiSuggestExtended);
                autoComplete.DropDownList.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your query and understood that you want to change the fontcolor on selecting the row in Autocomplete control. To achieve this, you can use the MetroColor property of AutoComplete control in AutoCompleteItemSelected event and the sample can be downloaded from following location:

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AutoCompleteCombo-352081038.zip

Please let us know if you need any other assistance on this.

Regards,

Vijayalakshmi VR